# What exactly is a bit vector in C++?

Tags: c++

So, I was reading a question in Cracking the Coding Interview: 5th Edition where it says to implement a bit vector with 4 billion bits. And it defines a bit vector as an array that compactly stores boolean values by using an array of ints. Each int stores a sequence of 32 bits, or boolean values. I am sort of confused in the above definition. Can someone explain me what exactly does the above statement mean?

The marked question that has been attached as duplicate, I couldn't really understand since their is no associated example. The second answer does have an example but it's not really understandable. It will be great if any of you can add an example, albeit for a small value only. Thanks!

Comment: A _good_ text would have recommended `int32_t` instead of assuming that `int` is 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

The `bool` type is at least 1 byte. It means it's at least 8 bits.
In a 'int' type, on a 32bits system, it's 32 bits.

You then have 32 booleans in 4 bytes with `int`, instead of 32 bytes minimum if you use `bool` type.

In an `int` you can store 32 booleans by basic bit operations : `&`, `|` and `~`

Comment: I got what you said, but how does the above bit vector exactly stores the values? I mean, can you give me a small example, let's say if I want to store numbers from 0-5??

Comment: @JohnLui: A bit by definition stores numbers from 0 to 1. It can't store 5.